# I think I got an infinite loop

Tags: java

Hi I'm new here and generally new to programming. My teacher told us to try our hands on a decimal to dual converter. Well I tried doing so and think I'm on the right way but somehow the code just keeps running without displaying the converted numbers. So I think there is probably an infinite loop inside of it but as a newbie programmer I just can't find it. Help would be appreciated.

Here is the code:

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class dezimalZuDual {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    int dezimalZahl = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Hier eine Dezimalzahl eingeben:"));
    int neu = dezimalZahl;
    String dualZahl = "";

    while(neu != 0)
    {
        neu = dezimalZahl / 2;
        String rest = Integer.toString(dezimalZahl - neu * 2);
        dualZahl = rest + dualZahl;

    }   
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Die Dezimalzahl " + dezimalZahl + " ist im Dualzahlensystem ausgedrückt: " + dualZahl + ".");
}
}
```

The code compiles without any errors for me the the message at the last line will just never be displayed.

Comment: Try using a debugger

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem here is that you're doing `neu = dezimalZahl / 2;`, which changes `neu`, but you never change `dezimalZahl`.

For example:

```
dezimalZahl = 10;
neu = 10/2 // (which is 5);
// rest of your code
```

And then you check `neu != 0`, which is true because it is 5. Then you run through your loop again, and you do the exact same thing, but `dezimalZahl` is still 10! That means `neu` will always be 5, which means you'll never leave the loop.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `neu` never changed

```
while(neu != 0)
    {
        neu = dezimalZahl / 2;
        String rest = Integer.toString(dezimalZahl - neu * 2);
        dualZahl = rest + dualZahl;

       //you are not changing(decreasing) value of neu
       //nor you are changing dezimalZahl which would affect neu value
       //so while loop returns true everytime and goes on
    }
```